# IEqualityComparer for nullable struct

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, iequalitycomparer

I want to write an equality comparer for Nullable structs. Lets say, `DateTime?`.
So I come up with this code:

```
public class NullableEntityComparer<TEntity, TType> : IEqualityComparer<TEntity> 
        where TType : struct
        where TEntity : Nullable<TType>
{
    public bool Equals(TEntity x, TEntity y)
    {
        if(!x.HasValue && ! y.HasValue) return true;
        if(x.HasValue && y.HasValue) return x.Value == y.Value;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TEntity obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        if (obj.HasValue) return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
        else return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like this and tells me:

```
'TType?' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
```

This is a clear message, however `Nullable<T>` is a class, and `TType?` is just a shorthand for `Nullable<TType>`. Or am I missing something?

Why does this not work? And is there a solution to have an `IEqualityComparer<T>` use the `T.HasValue` property?

Comment: "however `Nullable<T>` is a class" -- Huh? It's a `struct`.

Comment: from msdn: `where T: struct -> The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified.` More at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple - `Nullable<>` is a `struct`, so it counts as a sealed class, which is prohibited in a constraint (obviously - if you use a sealed class as a constraint, there's no need to use a generic type argument - you already always have exactly the same type).

But you don't need to do this at all. Simply have `TType` constrained by `struct`, but instead of using `TEntity`, just use `TType?` whenever you need the nullable:

```
public class NullableEntityComparer<TType> : IEqualityComparer<TType?> 
        where TType : struct
{
    public bool Equals(TType? x, TType? y)
    {
        if(!x.HasValue && ! y.HasValue) return true;
        if(x.HasValue && y.HasValue) return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TType? obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

As a side-note, nullables already have an implementation of equality that includes checking for nulls, so if you can avoid all this if you know the nullable type at compile-time.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "'TType?' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter." So indeed, not allowed. Period.

Comment: Your `if (obj == null)` check is wrong: `null` is a perfectly valid argument when the type is not a reference type, so you shouldn't throw an exception. The [`IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says: "The type of *obj* is a reference type and *obj* is **null**." as the condition for `ArgumentNullException`. Worse yet, it makes your `if (obj.HasValue)` check redundant. (But excellent answer nonetheless.)

Comment: In other words, he needs to abstract over `T`, but not over `Nullable`.

Comment: @hvd It's not my check, it's copied over from the OP. I cleaned it up already, though.

Comment: great solution, I feel so stupid now.
oh well, I'll accept your answer when stackoverflow allows me :)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked it in the question, thanks for pointing that out. :)